# Не работает метод Auth::login() в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, auth

В общем суть такова, у меня есть несколько баз данных, в каждой базе данных есть таблица пользователей с одинаковыми значениями в каждой базе данных `mysql`.

При авторизации пользователь выбирает базу данных в которой он зарегистрирован с помощью `select`.

Так вот я пытаюсь найти пользователя в удалённой базе данных и авторизовать его с помощью метода `login()` класса `Auth`, но почему то авторизации не происходит.

```
$dbResult = DB::connection($request->database)
            ->table("users")
            ->where("u_email",$request->email)
            ->where("u_password",$request->password)
            ->get();

 $user = new User();

$findUser =  $user::on($request->database)->where("u_email",$request->email)
            ->where("u_password",$request->password)->first();

  Auth::login($findUser);
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: покажи конфиг `/config/database.php`. Статический метод модели `User::on(string $connectionName)` принимает имя существующего соединения в конфиге `/config/database.php`

Comment: https://jeep-rap.ru/test/conf
В конгифе всё норм, когда выборку делаю из таблиц то модель есть, а вот авторизировать её метод не хочет

Comment: Какой ответ или ошибка возвращается при попытке авторизации?

Comment: в том то дело что никакого ответа нет, при попытке Auth::login($findUser) я перенаправляю на страницу профиля, и директива @auth показывает мне что пользователь не авторизирован

Answer (score 0):

у метода `\Auth::login($user, bool $remember = false)` есть второй параметр, который запоминает пользователя.

По умолчанию `$remember = false`, поэтому после редиректа пользователь уже не авторизован, т.к. это уже другой запрос